# Derivative in function

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, derivative

I'd like to write a Mathematica function that takes an expression as argument, takes the derivative of that expression, and then does something to the expression. So (as a toy example) I'd like to write

```
F[f_] = D[f, x] * 2
```

so that

```
F[x^2] = 4x
```

Instead, I get

```
F[x^2] = 0
```

Can someone point me to the relevant docs? I spent some time poking around the Mathematica reference, but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used assignment `=` when you mean to use delayed assignment `:=`. When you evaluate `F[f_]=D[f,x]*2` using (non-delayed) assignment, Mathematica looks at `D[f,x]` and sees that `f` (an unassigned symbol) does not depend on `x`; hence, its derivative is 0. Thus, `F[f_]=0` for any arguments to `F`, which is what it returns later.

If you want `F` to be evaluated only after you have specified what `f_` should be, you need to use delayed assignment by replacing `=` with `:=`.

Comment: Aha! So := is exactly what I was looking for; I didn't understand the distinction. Thank you!